# Webspeed in Cloudflare: Should I use Page Rules if I options are already selected in Speed and Caching?

Tags: browser-cache, cloudflare, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I want to improve the web speed with Cloudflare (Pro plan), and I have the following options already selected in the Speed and Caching sections of my Dashboard:

```
- Autominify (JavaScript, CSS, and HTML, selected)
- Brotli: On
- Enhanced HTTP/2 Prioritization: On
- Mirage: On
- Caching Level: Standard
- Browser Cache Expiration: 1 month
- Always Online: On
- Development Mode: Off
```

I wondered if, after having selected all these options, now I must set the Page Rules for every pages (for instance, for '* mydomain.com/ *'), or it's already activated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Those speed features are domain-wide settings, which will be effective for all web assets within your domain. Therefore, you will not need to use page rules on them any further. Unless you want to set fine-grained control to overwrite the domain-wide settings, for example disable auto-minify, cache-level, mirage etc for certain URI path, you can do so using page rules.